# Using .setShortcut() on OSX (Mac)

Tags: python, pyqt

On Windows this works just fine. But on OSX hitting Ctrl+B results to no action.
Is there any known issue with using .setShortcut() on Mac I should be aware of?

```
def functCall():
    print 'this'

menu = QtGui.QMenu()
menuItem=menu.addAction("myAction", functCall)
menuItem.setShortcut('Ctrl+B')
```

Comment: You haven't confused the "Ctrl" key with the "command" key right? Setting the shortcut to "Ctrl+B" means you need to press the command key + B (confusingly)

Comment: I have tried every key on my keyboard to make it work: Command, Option, Control... nothing works. Interesting that as soon as I hit the shortcut in Activity Monitor there is a new process started with funny name: `ParentalControlSd` . I have tried multiple times. And this process re-appears every time I hit keyboard shortcut. It stays in Activity Monitor for a few seconds and then it is gone till I hit shortcut again. And this story repeats.